# understanding solution for $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{9}{4}x}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I already have solution for this integral but I don't understand it. What happened at the end? Could anyone write steps in between? I thought that it'd be $\frac{1}{e^{\infty}} - -e^0 = 1$  so indeed it results into $1$ but why did they extract this $\frac{4}{9}$?

$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{9}{4}x} = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{4}{9}\frac{9}{4}e^{-\frac{9}{4}x} = \frac{4}{9}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{9}{4}e^{-\frac{9}{4}x} = \frac{4}{9}*1$

Comment: If you had remembered to put the $dx$, this wouldn't have happened.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like they did it to make the $u$-substitution clearer.

To solve this problem, you would write
$$u=\frac{9}{4}x,\quad \mathrm{d}u=\frac{9}{4}\mathrm{d}x$$
If you write out a factor of $\frac{9}{4}$, you can clearly see the $\mathrm{d}u$ can be substituted in, because $\frac{9}{4}\mathrm{d}x$ is already inside the integral. However, if you insert the $\frac{9}{4}$, you also have  to multiply by its reciprocal, $\frac{4}{9}$. This means that you've just multiplied the integral by $1$, leaving it unchanged. The operation is valid.

The $\frac{4}{9}$ is put outside the integrand because it is not a function of $x$ or $u$, but a constant, which can always be removed. It makes the integral less cluttered (in my opinion).

Once you do this, you have
$$\frac{4}{9}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-u}\mathrm{d}u$$
which is simple to solve.

On a side note, I might have instead done
$$u=-\frac{9}{4}x,\quad\mathrm{d}u=-\frac{9}{4}\mathrm{d}x$$
to end up with integrating $e^u$ instead of $e^{-u}$ (so I wouldn't forget to account for the $-$ sign, but that's simply personal preference.

Finally, when doing $u$-substitution, always be careful with the limits of the integral. In this case, the limits happened to be identical after the substitution, but this is generally not the case.

Comment: This whole mess came from my lack in education, of course, I though that interal of $e^{cx}$ is just $ce^{cx}$. Thank you for detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

You have that

$$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-\frac{9}{4}x}\ dx = \frac{4}{9}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{9}{4}e^{-\frac{9}{4}x}\ dx,$$

and an antiderivative of $\frac{9}{4}e^{-\frac{9}{4}x}$ is $-e^{-\frac{9}{4}x}$, so

$$\frac{4}{9}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{9}{4}e^{-\frac{9}{4}x}\ dx = \frac{4}{9}\left[-e^{-\frac{9}{4}x}\right]_0^{\infty}=\frac{4}{9}(0-(-1)) = \frac{4}{9}.$$